# Icons and the DivideByZero exception

Tags: c#, winforms, icons, size, gdi+

I have an owner drawn listbox which contains a list of structs representing the items.  This struct has two properties, an icon and a string to display.  It has worked fine for displaying small icons, 16x16 and thereabouts.  However, I tried to adapt this listbox to display pictures from a folder and have had some inexplicable errors.

```
public static System.Drawing.Icon BitmapToIcon (System.String String_Bitmap, System.Drawing.Icon Object_Default)
{
    try
    {
        //return System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(((System.Drawing.Bitmap)(System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(String_Bitmap))).GetHicon());
        System.IO.Stream s = new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(String_Bitmap));
        System.Drawing.Bitmap b = ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)(System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromStream(s, true, true)));
        System.Drawing.Icon i = System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(b.GetHicon());
        s.Close();
        b.Dispose();
        return i;
    }
    catch
    {
        return Object_Default;
    }
}
```

elsewhere:

```
BitmapToIcon("D:/pictures/picture001.jpg", null);
```

The directory has about 400 images of all shapes and formats, but only about 60, randomly spaced apart, actually appear in the listbox.  In ListBox.DrawItem(), Graphics.DrawIcon() is throwing a DivideByZero function.  On trapping the exception, it's registering the icons as 0x0.  My function is quite obviously written to return a default icon (null in this case) in the event of an error.

I know the Windows ICO format has a 256x256 limit, but that's not what's happening here as far as I can tell.  Some of the images it DOES draw are really much larger and they're not square either.  Further, all of the images it won't load in a list of 400 load just fine in a list of 10.  I thought maybe GDI had too many handles or something so I changed the function to dispose my source bitmaps and added a sleep statement but neither helped.  Changing the listbox to use Bitmaps instead of Icons fixed the drawing problem but it now consumes much more memory.

Is there some reason the GetHIcon() would be returning such weird results like this and what can I do about it?

Comment: I would *HIGHLY* recommend using the [`Using (`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.100).aspx) statement.

Comment: Is really unclear where the problem is.  You haven't provided the code that calls method that throws the exception and you haven't detailed whether the exception is thrown when you try to draw Object_Default or not.

Comment: Peter, please try reading the question again.  I very clearly stated that the exception is being thrown by Graphics.DrawIcon() in the ListBox's DrawItem().

Comment: private void ICONLIST_DrawItem (System.Object Object_Sender, System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs Object_Arguments)
    {
        RK.ICONLIST.RECORD Struct_Temporary = ((RK.ICONLIST.RECORD)(this.Items[Object_Arguments.Index]));
        System.Drawing.Rectangle Rectangle_Graphic = Object_Arguments.Bounds;
        try{Object_Arguments.Graphics.DrawIcon((Struct_Temporary.Graphic ?? this.SafeIcon), Rectangle_Graphic);}
        catch(System.Exception e){System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer.DrawText(Object_Arguments.Graphics, e.Message);}
    }

Comment: Also Eric I tried the using statement and it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Ryan, Eric means that it's would be better yo use using directive to avoid code like:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap b = ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)(System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromStream(s, true, true)));
```

After refactor it would looks like:

```
using System.Drawing.Bitmap;

Bitmap b = ((Bitmap)(Bitmap.FromStream(s, true, true)));
```

It's hard to read code you provided.
Try to use Image.FromFile()  function to load you image or use Bitmap constructor with path parameter.

```
    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(String_Bitmap);
    Icon i = Icon.FromHandle(b.GetHicon());
```

Comment: Bitmap derives from the abstract Image so either FromFile() should do the same thing.  It really looks like it comes down to Bitmap being smarter about GDI handles than Icon.

Comment: If using bitmaps got many resources, try to implement your listbox as virtual listbox, where main idea is to show only visible items and draw another only if user scroll items. May be you show listbox sources to find out why it take so much resources and how you can refactor it to work properly and fast.

Answer (score 0):

You should trap the error in your catch clause to see what kind of exception is causing the default icon to be returned.

If you never call *DestroyIcon* and call this method repeatedly it may well be that you are running out of GDI resourses.

May I also suggest that this code is equivalent to your code and a little easier to read:

```
    using ( var b = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(String_Bitmap))
        return Icon.FromHandle(b.GetHicon());
```

Also - why don't you change the struct for your listbox to work with bitmaps instead of icons and just get rid of this icon problem? :-)

Comment: Yes, I tried about a dozen different variations of BitmapToIcon(), many including a call to DestroyIcon(), with almost as many weird side effects.  One would appear to load all the icons only to crash about 3/4 of the way down with "cannot access disposed icon" even though I hadn't done any such thing and another returned 0x0 for everything.  I turned on the GDI counter in TaskManager and it was sucking up over 1000 handles for 400 icons vs about 95 if I used bitmaps.

Comment: When I trap the exception in BitmapToIcon() I get "a generic GDI error occurred."  Searching online says that's a catch all for many errors, among them leaking handles, so it isn't much help.

Comment: As for why I don't use Bitmaps, it's only partly out of stubbornness.  One, I use BitmapToIcon() in a few other places for actual 16x16 icons, and two, if you think about it, a listbox full of Bitmaps _should_ have the same problems.  They're both GDI objects with handles inside of a struct I'm accessing through ListBox.Items[].  Why one (BitmapListBox) works and the other (IconListBox) goes bananas is beyond me.

Comment: One other variation _did_ draw all of the icons but it really screwed up treeviews and comboboxes in other applications which I presume was due to the GDI handle limit.  It's as if the .NET Icon, like the .NET Font, is implemented just enough to be used occasionally (like setting a window icon) but turns into a disaster quickly if you really start doing anything serious with it.  I guess in lieu of any other alternatives I'm going to have to mark "use a BitmapListBox instead" as the answer...

Comment: Heck I even tried a version where my struct only held onto a pointer to the icon because I thought maybe the copy of the struct coming out of Items[] was being collected and its icon property disposed.

Comment: Yes, I would recommend Bitmaps over Icons because there is much better support for them in .Net. In particular, I alsmot always work with .Png files because of the 8 bit alpha channel, as opposed to the regular icones which has only 1 bit alpha.